# jQuery live() not showing text cursor in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm using the jQuery `live()` function to change the border colour of form text inputs to give users a better indication of what element they are currently typing in. It's easier for me to use `live()` over `bind()` as there are certain instances where new form inputs are inserted into the page dynamically.

From reading through the jQuery [documentation for `live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) I understand that each handler must return false to prevent other handlers from executing. Whether or not I'm misinterpreting what this actually means, here is the code I have to add and remove the border colour from my form inputs.

```
$('input.highlight').live({
    focus: function() {
        $(this).parent('span').addClass('input-focus');
        return false;
    },
    blur: function() {
        $(this).parent('span').removeClass('input-focus');
        return false;
    }
});
```

This works perfectly in Chrome and Safari except in Firefox the flashing text cursor does not appear inside the form input when it has focus. If I remove `return false;` it shows. Could this be a jQuery bug that I've encountered?

Comment: Its to do with the way .live bubbles up and that return false blocks some events higher up the chain from acting

Comment: So what is it that Chrome and Safari do in between me setting the border colour class and return false or after the return that Firefox is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey, I had the same problem. I overcame the problem by adding $(this).focus(); before the return false.

```
$('input.highlight').live({
    focus: function() {
        $(this).parent('span').addClass('input-focus');
        $(this).focus();
        return false;
    },
    blur: function() {
        $(this).parent('span').removeClass('input-focus');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.